# Laravel passport add scope to already authorized user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am using `laravel 5.6` and `passport` for authorize my users

In `passport` i am using `Personal Access Tokens`

Here i generate token for authenticated user with `foo` scope :

```
$accessToken = $user->createToken('App', ['foo'])->accessToken;
```

After that how can i add `bar` scope to my user without regenerating token?

Comment: You cannot add or update the scopes after the token is generated.

Comment: why not? there must be a way

Answer (score 1):

there is a table named `oauth_access_tokens`. Passport store scopes for each token there. You can update scopes there for that token

```
DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
        ->where('id', $token)
        ->update(['read','write']); //scopes array
```

If you check passport source file, they are also using this way for insert

Comment: There must be an implemented method for this